If the signal is not bandlimited, then we’ll always have an issue with aliasing, what does this statement mean?
In my book it says in the Aliasing section that, if a signal is not bandlimited then we will always have a problem with aliasing. I don't understand how not being bandlimited could cause that? By principle, aliasing is caused by undersampling, so if I make sure that the signal is sampled at a rate higher than twice the bandwidth of the frequency specturm, then I'll never have any issues with aliasing.
My textbook definitions
Bandlimited:
For a signal to be bandlimited in frequency, it has to be everlasting in time goes (-infinity, infinity).

Not bandlimited.

Bandlimited, after applying antialising filter.
** FIXED TYPO ERRORS **

question: how does the symbol "B" relate to the bandlimitation of a signal?  (that is, what does "B" mean? and what does "bandlimited" mean?)

What is $B$ for a signal that is not band-limited?

B refers to Bandwidth of the signal spectrum.

@ECEStudent: Right, but what is its value for a signal that is not band-limited?

What textbook is that??

Signals & Systems: Theory and Applications by Fawwaz T. Ulaby and Andrew E. Yagle

Not being time-limited is a necessary condition for a signal to have finite bandwidth, but it's not sufficient.

@ECEStudent can you, in your own words explain what it means for a signal to be bandlimited? you just state one condition for it. But "in order to be fast, a car needs to have fuel" is not a definition of "fast", just like "in order to be bandlimited, a signal has to be infinite in time" is not a definition of "bandlimited".
